# Wygwam and IE10, Enter key doesn't function in IE10

Tags: wygwam

Just visited a client that has Wygwam v2.4.0.2 and EE 2.4.0. The Enter key wouldn't function in IE10. Worked fine in Chrome. Is this a known bug that was fixed in an updated version of Wygwam? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, Mike - I just tested in Wygwam  2.7, EE 2.5.5, and IE 10.  The enter key adds new lines perfectly.  Are you seeing any JS errors in the debug console?  It is likely worth upgrading to 2.7 before continuing to troubleshoot.

Comment: Lisa, I upgraded to 2.7 and just heard back from the client that it still doesn't work. Unfortunately I didn't check for errors while I was there.

Comment: is it possible to get super admin access to the site? If so, please email support@pixelandtonic.com and reference this thread. Thanks!

Comment: Lisa, Just installed IE10 to test and the Enter key and it worked fine. It must be something with the client's system. I'll have to check for errors the next time I'm in there. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Mike - awesome!  If you find out what's happening, will you share? I haven't run across this before and I'd love to know what's going on. :) Please let me know if I can help at all!

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a bug in CKEditor. If you can, try upgrading to the latest version of Wygwam (v2.7), which is using a slightly newer version of CKEditor that includes fixes for greater IE10 compatibility.